# Auto PostBack in uiscrollview when user scrolls 75% of the way down

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How do I check if the user scrolls down 75% of the way down?  I want to implement a postback to load more data but I'm not sure how to accomplish this... I would greatly appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction or show some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set your scrollview delegate. And on scrollViewDidScroll method you need to calculate scroll position. 
This should cover your goals

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height)/scrollView.contentSize.height) > 0.75) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!